# Trio execution time without IO operations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-trio

I'm doing examples to understand how it works python asynchronously. I read the Trio documentation and I thought that only one task can be executed in the loop every time and in every `checkpoint` the `scheduler` decide which task will be executed.

I did an example to test it, in the trio example I don't use any checkpoint in the child that I spawn in the `nursery` but this example is two times faster than the synchronous version.

Async example:

```
import time
import trio

results = []

async def sum_numbers(first, last):
    result = 0
    for i in range(first, last):
        result += i
    results.append(result)

async def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        nursery.start_soon(sum_numbers, 0, 50000000)
        nursery.start_soon(sum_numbers, 50000000, 100000000)

    print(sum(results))
    print("Total time:", time.time() - start_time)

trio.run(main)
```

Result:

```
4999999950000000
Total time: 4.150018930435181
```

Sync example:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
result = 0
for i in range(0, 100000000):
    result += i

print(result)
print("Total time:", time.time() - start_time)
```

Result:

```
4999999950000000
Total time: 8.002650737762451
```

Why? I expected the same time because I'm not using any checkpoint in my code. Seems like there are 2 threads running at the same time or Is there any I/O in the child function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a small talk with the Trio author, [Nathaniel J. Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925449/nathaniel-j-smith) he found the problem in my code. The problem is in the synchronous example. I'm using global variables instead of local variables like in the asynchronous example.

Nathaniel: "In CPython, accessing locals is more optimized than accessing globals. (the compiler converts locals into offsets-in-an-array, while globals are always looked up by name in a dict)"

Then I put all the code from the sync example in a function and the time is similar of async, even faster. Now make sense, this was the theory and now is proved, it's clear for me. Thank you!

Sync example in a function:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()


def sum_range():
    result = 0
    for i in range(0, 100000000):
        result += i

    return result

print(sum_range())
print("Total time:", time.time() - start_time)
```

Result:

```
4999999950000000
Total time: 3.596266984939575
```